# Error resolving version for plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:maven-war-plugin' from the repositories

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss

I am using eclipse Indigo Service Release 2 with *JBoss* tools installed and created a Seam Web project with Maven integration selected. After the project is created, I got this error in my pom.xml file, does anybody know how to resolve it? thanks

```
Error resolving version for plugin 'org.codehaus.mojo:maven-war-plugin'
from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Jon\.m2\repository), 
jboss-public-repository-group 
(https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/),
central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)]: 
Plugin not found in any plugin repository
```

I also tried to create a new Seam web project with Maven integration again, this is the step I followed: http://docs.jboss.org/tools/nightly/trunk/en/seam/html/create_mavenized_seam.html#create_mavenized_project
After the project is created, I got these error in eclipse api, all are related to pom.xml (with a red sign)

```
Missing artifact org.jboss.tools:Maven2:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.faces:jboss-jsf-    api_2.0_spec:jar is missing.
Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to transfer 

org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-web-6.0:pom:${javaee6.web.spec.version} 
from https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ was 
cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted 
until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed 
or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact 
org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-web-6.0:pom:${javaee6.web.spec.version} 
from/to jboss-public-repository-group    
(https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/): 
Illegal character in path at index 94: 
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-web-6.0/    
${javaee6.web.spec.version}/jboss-javaee-web-6.0-${javaee6.web.spec.version}.pom
```

No sure why I got different error each time, I use eclipse indigo new version 64big downloaded here:https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2
and add jboss tools from Marketplace, with Jboss server and Seam famework. Based on the error, do I have install any plugins? it is so confusing, because I got different error each time.

Comment: I deleted this project and create a new one, but I got different error this time, these are:Missing artifact org.jboss.tools:Maven2:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Project build error: 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec.javax.faces:jboss-jsf-api_2.0_spec:jar is missing.
Project build error: Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to transfer 
org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-web-6.0:pom:${javaee6.web.spec.version} 
from https://repository.jboss.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong groupId, it should be `org.apache.maven.plugins`. And another hint: use https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/ instead of public, because the public repo is a group containing a lot of other repo's, both releases and SNAPSHOTs.

Comment: The thing is that all the errors are coming  from pom.xml, from what I understanding, the content in pom..xml are built automatically in eclipse framework when create a new seam maven project, I should not add it manually.